# uninitialized constant Sass::Rails::SassTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, activeadmin

I am using Rails 3.1.1 and active_admin gem. Everything is running perfect in Development env but when I try to do `rake db:migrate` in Production env I get this error

```
   uninitialized constant Sass::Rails::SassTemplate
```

What might be the issue and how do I fix it?

In my gemfile i have `gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'`

Comment: Have you put this gem in your production group in your Gemfile?

Comment: nope. Is is in the assets group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would either of [these](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/447) [two](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/38) github issues relate to your problem? I see they're submitted by the same person, but they may receive different replies.

Answer (score 7):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308078/272342) by Spencer gives the right solution. But to avoid you to look at the two issues in GitHub and wondering which of the multiple propositions work -pushing to production just to test this can be tedious-, let me explicit the [fix](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/38#issuecomment-2046678):

The `sass-rails` gem must be taken **out** of the `:assets` group:

```
gem 'sass-rails'

gem 'activeadmin' # (sass-rails must be loaded before!)
  gem 'meta_search',    '>= 1.1.1'
#end

group :assets do
  # Remove the line gem 'sass-rails' from here
end
```

As `activeadmin` uses `sass`, I assumed the `sass` line must appear before `activeadmin`. But I did not test the other way.

In case anyone wonders, the indentation of the `meta_search` line and the `#end` is just my way of remembering why I added this other gem. Just a hint to my future self that if I remove the gem `activeadmin`, there is a high chance that I can also remove the gem `meta_search`.